# question on Rashi to M'nachos 57

Tags: rashi, chametz-leaven, drush, mincha-meal-offering, maseches-menachos

The top *Rashi* on [*Menachos* 57:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4503&size=1), if I'm reading it correctly, adds some information as an aside, stating that both *Rabi Akiva* and *Rabi Yose Hag'lili* derive from "*asher takrivu*" that a *mincha* of a *kohen* (or perhaps he means specifically the inaugural *mincha* of a *kohen*) and the inaugural *mincha* of the *kohen gadol* may not be made *chametz*.

Two questions, of which I'm especially bothered by the second:

1. How does *Rashi* know that they learn this *halacha* from this *pasuk*?
2. Why does *Rashi* mention this fact here? He should, I'd think, have mentioned it, if anywhere, as a comment on the passage just before, where the *tanaim* were quoted.

Comment: About the first question: I haven't learned that specific place, but I wan to note that rishonim knew plenty of things that were not written down in gemara (don't forget, we are dealing with oral torah).

Comment: Drush? I know it doesn't have a tag-wiki, but I have always veiwed it more in the realm of midreshei aggada not midreshei halacha.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't spend too much time on this, but off the cuff:

Without the reasoning of "nesachim is fruit juice and cannot come to chimutz", I could have said the R"Y haGelili and R"A are adding only one item- whichever is the lesser chidush to include.  The statement of reasoning shows that the machlokes is not over which one is the simplest to include, but rather that R"A holds that nesachim cannot be included practically.  However, if it could come to chimutz, R"A would admit that it is included.  So from that statement of reasoning, we see that the ribui includes all that is practical.

Admittedly, I probably would not have noticed your point.